# Android mvp startService in model

Tags: android, mvp

How can I start a service from a model, if it needs a context.

My problem is, that the view and model do not know anything about each other.

Tell me, if i must use other pattern.

Comment: service from model?? Model is just a holder for your data.. what causes it to start a service? could you please more precise??

Comment: For example. I write app with sockets, and I need socket server. I think that put it in service. Where is i must start this service if i use mvp?

Comment: The thing is, View could interact with presenter through interface and presenter with model, so having to start with a presenter is not a bad one. I suggest you to start service from presenter which had context passed from view and has access with model.

Comment: I did so. I was hit by an article in someone's blog. now I realized that this is stupid. Thanks. Add as answer, I mark this

Comment: Yeah sure.. Added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, View could interact with presenter through interface and presenter with model, so having to start with a presenter is not a bad one. I suggest you to start service from presenter which had context passed from view and has access with model.

Try giving a read to this article :

[Link Here](https://medium.com/@cervonefrancesco/model-view-presenter-android-guidelines-94970b430ddf)

Comment: One more question. Presenter communicate with model by interface or directly?

Comment: "Make sure that presenter doesn’t depend on Android classes", you can't start the service from presenter since context is an android thing